# Python-decouple raises a warning while importing in settings.py? [PYTHON DJANGO]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, environment-variables, pipenv

[USING PYCHARM]

I'm trying to use `.env` file details in `settings.py` using `python-decouple`. `decouple` installed perfectly but when I tried to import it, it raises a warning: `Package containing module 'decouple' is not listed in project requirements`.
you can see the package details from here:
https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/3.1/

[warning i'm getting while importing decouple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZsYb.png)

error in terminal : `raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))`

`decouple.UndefinedValueError: EMAIL_BACKEND not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.`

`.env` file

```
export EMAIL_BACKEND=django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
export EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
export EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
export EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
export EMAIL_PORT=587
export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx;
```

`settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND')
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

I tried creating requirements.txt and added `python-decouple==3.3` in it but  it still not working.
one more thing i'm using `pipenv` package was that can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.env` file to

```
EMAIL_BACKEND=django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx;
```

Remove export `keywords` from your `.env` file.

Comment: o gosh. How can i be so wrong there. thanx for your help

Comment: yes. actually earlier i was using io.environ() which require export but that was not working so i shifted to decouple and forgot to remove export from it